# Acquiring inner-class lock using outer-class locks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have an outer class A and that has a public inner class, the structure is as follows -:

```
public class A{

      public int x;

      public class B{
        private static final int y;
      }

      public synchronized int method1(){
             return x+ B.y;
      }
}
```

the question is if I used synchronized keyword on every method of the class A will it also lock the members of the inner class as well?

Answer (score 1):

> if I used synchronized keyword on every method of the class A will it also lock the members of the inner class as well?

No it won't.

You seem to be confused in a number of respects here.

- Using a primitive mutex (e.g. via a `synchronized` method) *only* locks against other threads that are synchronizing on *the same* mutex.
- When you call a synchronized instance method, the mutex you are acquiring is the mutex for `this` ... the target object.
- In your example, it seems that you want to lock a `static` field, not an instance field.

---

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, the correct way to do it is something like this:

```
 public synchronized int method1(){
     synchronized (B.class) {
         return x + B.y;
     }
 }
```

Note that this involves acquiring *two* mutexes, so you need to make sure that your code always acquires them in the same order.  (If you don't, then there is a risk of deadlocks.)

You would get the same effect if you created and called a synchronized static method on `B` for getting the value of the `y` field.

Comment: actually I am working on the problem of coarse grain locking a linked list data structure where I have the following structure -:                  class LList{ public class Node{} public class InsertNode{}} and when a thread lets say T1 acquires a lock on the linked list data structure I want to ensure no other thread acquires a lock on either the individual nodes in the list and nor the list data structure how do I ensure that to happen.

Comment: @AnkitSablok - As above.  Use two objects as mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

No, the inner class and outer class are two different class objects, they will not be the same. I suggest creating a field in the outer class to manually synchronize on.

Comment: can you give an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

An example with a single mutex on 2 objects. Both Objects can change a variable x.

```
public class A {

      private Object mutex = new Object();
      private int x;
      private B b = new B();

      public class B {
        private int y;

        public int method() {        
           synchronized(mutex) {
              return x++;
          }

        }
      }

      public int method() {

          synchronized(mutex) {
             return x += b.y;
         }
      }
}
```