# Why inner class method cannot synchronized the object in outer class?

Tags: java, synchronized

I encountered a problem:Will inner class method cannot synchronized the object in outer class? A answer from stackoverflow told me : No. But I really want to know the reason.

For example:
    I designed a thread pool with at most 5 threads to do work.

```
public class ThreadPool{

     // Ignore the Task class 
     private LinkedList<Task> tasks;

     Executor[] executors = new Executor[5];

     private static ThreadPool pool = null;

     private ThreadPool() {
        tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executors[i] = new Executor(i);

        }
    }

    public static ThreadPool getInstance() {
        if (pool == null) {
            pool = new ThreadPool();
        }
        return pool;
    }

    public void addTask(Task task) {
        /** igore code here*/
    }

    private class Executor extends Thread {

        private int i;
        public Executor(int i) {
            this.i = i;
            start();
        }

                public void run() {
                Task task = null;
                synchronized (tasks) {

                    if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                        System.out.println("tasks's size is : " + tasks.size());
                        try {

                            while (tasks.size() == 0) {
                                tasks.wait();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (tasks.size() > 0)
                        task = tasks.removeFirst();
                }
                if (task != null) {
                    /** ignore code here */
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the synchronized doesn't  work. But when I put the synchronized block into

```
synchronized (ThreadPool.this) {
 ...
}
```

it works.

So, i want to know why inner class method cannot synchronized the object in outer class.

Hope for a detailed answer.

Comment: You have only `synchronized (tasks)`. What code doesn't work?

Comment: when I called getInstance() ,and then its constructor will be called. And the 5 five threads will all call the run method! if the synchronized works,only one thread can obtain the monitor and execute the code.

Comment: "So, i want to know why inner class method cannot synchronize the object in outer class.". It can. You did it, when you added `synchronized (ThreadPool.this)`.

Comment: if only synchronized (tasks), System.out.println("tasks's size is : " + tasks.size());  this line will be executed 5 times (one thread one once)

Comment: So? Are you perhaps really asking why you don't get some kind of free extra synchronization other than the one you're actually writing? Because you don't. You get what you write, nothing more.

Comment: i want to know what exactly synchronized (ThreadPool.this) do ? why cannot synchronize without it ?

Comment: @ChenZhongPu you can sinchronize without it. But first explain what is wrong with this way.

Comment: without it, the five threads will execute the run() method. However, the Java Doc says, once a thread get the monitor of an object, other thread cannot execute the synchronized code (and will wait until being released).@talex

Comment: You can see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910773/locking-and-synchronization-between-outer-and-inner-class-methods