# How to syncronize nested Java class method on parent class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have two classes

```
public class A {
    private byte[] buf;
    public synchronized void foo() {
        // does something with buf
    }
    public class B {
        public synchronized void bar() {
            // also does something with buf
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, method `bar()` is synchronized on an instance of class `B`. How can I synchronize it on the object of class `A` in order to protect the `buf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18910839/3888450), you can do the following:

```
public class A {
    private byte[] buf;

    public synchronized void foo() {
        // does something with buf
    }

    public class B {
        public void bar() {
            synchronized (A.this) {
                // also does something with buf
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works only, since you use a nested class that has a reference to its parent class. However, if you only want to synchronize the usage of the variable `buf` you can also do this:

```
public class A {
    private byte[] buf;

    public void foo() {
        synchronized (buf) {
            // does something with buf
        }
    }

    public class B {
        public void bar() {
            synchronized (buf) {
                // also does something with buf
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `synchronized (A.this)` is what I need. Thank you!